# How to add buttons without submit the form in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In Angular, how I add button without submit the form?

for example I want to call `onCancel` without submit the form, but update button should be submit the form, and still keep the `ngSubmit`.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <p>
    <select ...>...</select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <button
        type="submit"
        mat-raised-button
        color="primary">
        update
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCancel($event)">
        cancel
    </button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Just add `type='button'` to it.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Just add `type='button'` to it. A button without any defined `type` in a form acts like a `submit` button for the form.

Comment: It won't work without passing the `$event` object to the callback!

Answer (score 27):

There are three types of buttons:

- submit : submits the current form data. `(This is default.)`
- reset : rsets data in the current form.
- button : just a button. Its effects
  must be controlled by something else (that is, with JavaScript).

so you only need to update the type attribut to **button**

template

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="onCancel($event)">
    cancel
</button>
```

[resources](http://%20https://html.com/attributes/button-type/#ixzz5l9Pbap98)

Comment: It won't work without passing the `$event` object to the callback!

Answer (score 4):

Remove `(ngSubmit)="submit()"` in the form tag and put it in button like so:

```
<button
    (click)="submit()"
    mat-raised-button
    color="primary">
    update
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `type="button"`, if you don't mention any type then by default the button is considered as submit type. So you code should look something like this for the non submit button.

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="onCancel($event)">
        cancel
</button>
```

Comment: It won't work without passing the `$event` object to the callback!

Answer (score 3):

You can add `$event.preventDefault()` to button click event

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="onCancel($event); $event.preventDefault()">
```

Answer (score 1):

overall i don't like idea that default button type is submit, i created following directive to make things right, buttons witout type set explicitly defaults to button:

```
@Directive(
{
   selector: 'button:not([type])'
})
export class ButtonTypeDirective implements OnInit
{
   constructor(private el: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>, private renderer: Renderer2) 
   {
   }

   public ngOnInit()
   {
       this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'type', 'button');
   }
}
```

Comment: I wish there was some sort of linter/formatter that would make sure the type is defined. I couldn't find such a thing and I'm considering using this approach, since it happens very often that I forget to add the button type and that results in unintentional form submissions.

Comment: Thanks! This was the best answer, I just don't know why it did not get any up vote!